# Determining Change of Basis Matrix for Linear Transformation from Eigenbasis to Standard Basis

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

I am seeking assistance in understanding and computing the change of basis matrix (M) for a linear transformation from the **Eigenbasis** (B) to an **Standard Basis** (A). Specifically, I have a linear transformation **T** that maps **R^2 to R^2**, projecting onto the vector

> **v** = (1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)).
>
> The matrix representation of **T** in the standard basis (A) is given
> as [(1/2, 1/2), (1/2, 1/2)].

> Now, I find the matrix representation of **T** in the **eigenbasis**
> (B) of **T**, which is [(1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)), (-1/sqrt(2),
> 1/sqrt(2))]. The desired matrix in basis B is [(1, 0), (0, 0)].

I understand that the relationship between the matrices in the two bases is given by the formula: **matrix of T in B = M^-1 * matrix of T in A * M.**

Therefore, my question is twofold:

1. Why does the change of basis matrix (**M**) for a linear transformation **T**, from basis A to basis B, correspond to the columns of basis B? I have managed to obtain the correct result in this particular case as

> **M** = [(1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2)), (-1/sqrt(2), 1/sqrt(2))],

but I am looking for a more general understanding of this phenomenon.

2. Additionally, I have encountered an issue when attempting to retrieve the matrix representation of **T** in the **standard basis** (A) when given the matrix of **T** in the **eigenbasis** (B). In this scenario, using the formula **matrix of T in A = M^-1 * matrix of T in B * M**, where

> M is the change of basis matrix [(1, 1), (1, 1)],

I find that the result is the matrix of **T** in the **eigenbasis** (B) again. Could someone provide insights into why this is occurring and guide me on the correct steps to obtain the matrix representation of **T** on the **standard basis**?

Comment: Please use MathJax to write math expressions in your post. A quick guide can be found [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).